# Pentaho DI - Table Input error "couldn't get row from result set"

Tags: mysql, date, pentaho

I get an error in Pentaho Data Integration while creating an ETL that extracts from a MySQL database.

Specifically, I get an error in the VERY first step called "Table Input". The connection is fine so I know that is not the problem. I get a problem with even the very first row.

This paragraph is part of the log of the error:

```
2017/01/11 12:26:00 - IN R.A.L..0 - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2017/01/11 12:26:00 - IN R.A.L..0 - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2017/01/11 12:26:00 - IN R.A.L..0 - Couldn't get row from result set
2017/01/11 12:26:00 - IN R.A.L..0 - 
2017/01/11 12:26:00 - IN R.A.L..0 - Unable to get value 'Date' from database resultset, index 63
2017/01/11 12:26:00 - IN R.A.L..0 - Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp
2017/01/11 12:26:00 - IN R.A.L..0 - 
2017/01/11 12:26:00 - IN R.A.L..0 -
```

I can "suppose" it is a value in the row declared as timestamp that has a 0000-00-00, but I checked and double checked, and that is not it! I do have a timestamp but its value is not 0000-00-00 as it says in the log, and the one column that does have a 0000-00-00 is not a timestamp but a Date, so...

I'm obviously missing something, otherwise I wouldn't be asking, so thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to reply. I asked the same question directly in the pentaho forum and it was solved.

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?217544-Table-input-error-quot-couldn-t-get-row-from-result-set-quot

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which row is causing issue you can add 2 text file output steps just after  your table input steps. Connect one output step with true records (you will see green correct symbol on hop)-lets say `output-A` and one with false records(you will see red X symbol on hop)-lets say `output-B`. This way the transformation will not fail and it will send the error causing record into `output-B`. This way you can see which records is causing issue and compare it with the other ones.

Answer (score -3):

using this function resolved it for me.

`date_format(data_cadastro_cli,"%Y-%m-%d")`